# Classname instancename=value" is the same as "Classname instancename=new Classname () ;instancename=value"?

Tags: c#

```
TestClass p=new Testclass();
p=value;

TestClass p=value;
```

I ran some tests and they appear to be the same but I want to be sure it isn't a problem that the second has no "new" keyword.

Sorry for newbie question, thank you for your help.

Comment: How is value created? Probably there is a new  involved ... somewhere.

Comment: `p=value;` Did you mean `var value = p;`? If the code really is as you show it, you should always use your latter code sample - since the former one creates an object and then basically throws it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do below

```
1.TestClass p=new Testclass(); //this will create new p 

2. var value = new Testclass();
TestClass p=value;//this will assign already created instance to p i.e. reference assignment
```

in first create it all together new object , but in second case when you assign reference , then value and p both point to same instace , so if you do change like

```
value.property = 'abc';//it affect p
p.property = 'xyz';// it affect value
```

this happens because both point to same object.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you didn't do enough tests, because there *is* a crucial difference. If you had:

```
var value1 = new TestClass();
var value2 = new testClass();

value1.Foo = "Bar";
value2.Foo = "Baz";

Console.WriteLine($"Val 1: {value1.Foo}, Val 2: {value2.Foo}");
```

You will get `"Val 1: Bar, Val 2: Baz"`, as expected, but if you did:

```
var value1 = new TestClass();
TestClass value2 = value1;

// ...The rest as before
```

You get:  `"Val 1: Baz, Val 2: Baz"`.

This happened, because `value2` actually points to the same object as `value1`. This can be though of giving two people addresses to a real location on a notecard, and whenever they need that location, they refer to that notecard.

This, in programming, is the address or reference of the variable, ie, where it is stored in the memory. When they have the same address, whatever you do to when variable, will effect the other, much like if one person painted the house the notecard refers to, the other person will see those changes.

However, to make things trickier:

```
var value1 = new TestClass();
var value3 = new TestClass();
TestClass value2 = value1;   // Value2 is now sharing the reference of value1
                             // Any changes to value2 will effect value1
value2 = null;               // This does not set the value of value1 to null
value2 = value3;             // This does not set the value of value1 to value3
```

Going back to the analogy, what we're doing when we assign one reference type variable to another, we're giving a person a new notecard with a different address on it. Obviously this isn't going to change whatever the original location was to be whatever is at the new location.

In programming, we're just telling it what object to reference for now. If you do want the behavior of `value2 = null` makes `value1` `null` as well, there's still a way to do that.